# New email create from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have email register in Excel. I need to create Command Button to open new email with last row details. i.e. last row, column C , column F . Please note there are hundreds of rows are existing with previously sent emails. How to write codes for that Command Button.

Thanks in advance

Hewage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*It works with below

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim rngSubject As Range
    Dim rngBody As Range
    Dim rngAttach As Range

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    a = ActiveCell.Row

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngTo = .Cells(a, "C")
        Set rngSubject = .Cells(a, "E")
        'Set rngBody = .Range("B3")
        'Set rngAttach = .Range("B4")
    End With

    With objMail
        .To = rngTo.Value
        .Subject = rngSubject.Value
        '.Body = rngBody.Value
       '.Attachments.Add rngAttach.Value
        .Display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
                    or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
    End With

    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set rngTo = Nothing
    Set rngSubject = Nothing
    Set rngBody = Nothing
    Set rngAttach = Nothing
End Sub
```

Regards,
Hewage

Answer (score 0):

```vb
set wbNew = application.workbooks.add
set wsNew = wbNew.sheets(1)

thisworkbook.rows(intLastRow).copy wsNew.rows(1)
wbnew.sendmail(stRecipients)
```

Something like that?

Or are you saying the last row contains the details you want to email? "sendmail" gives you ability to specify recipients and subject, but you might wanna look at Outlook object instead (add through Tools/References) then you can do something like:

```
Set apOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
apOutlook.Session.Logon

Set itEmail = apOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With itEmail
    .To = stRecipient
    .Subject = stSubject
    .Body = stBody
    .Display
End With
```

i.e. adds ability to specify "body" and will pop up an Outlook email object rather than the unsightly "An application is trying to send an email on your behalf" window that SendMail does...

Comment: H Simon, As per your 2nd option, New email open without "To" and "Subject". those details in my excel sheet column C and E, last row. My question is how to get email id and subject from cells to new email.